# Replace function says item expected sequence found

Tags: xquery, xslt-2.0

I have the source XML like below, I am extracting title text with all the subelements string except "unwantedtag" content using except function. When I try to add the dot at the end of the title using the replace function. I am getting an error says item expected sequence found. Can anyone help me why I am getting this error and how to solve this:

Sample XML:

```
<test>
<title>sample <i>title</i><sup>*</sup> 
    <unwantedcontent>
        <p>unwanted text.</p>
    </unwantedcontent>
</title>
<p2>sampletest2</p2>
</test>
```

Xquery:

```
 for $k in (test/*:title)
 let $s1:= $k//text() except (.//*:unwantedcontent)//text()
 let $s2 := replace($s1, "(.*)([^.])$", "$1$2.")
 return $s2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `$s1` is going to comprise three text nodes ("sample ", "title", "*") plus possibly a couple of whitespace-only text nodes depending on how the source document was parsed. I think you probably want to concatenate these text nodes, and perhaps trim the trailing whitespace, before adding the ".". This would be

```
let $s2 := replace(normalize-space(string-join($s1, '')), "(.*)([^.])$", "$1$2.")
```

Comment: That's great @Micheal Kay, this is what exactly I was trying to get string-join doing the magic here. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it works. The convention on StackOverflow is that if the answer works, you don't need to say thanks, instead you should tick the check-box next to the answer to mark it as accepted.